# Reach cookie from external script within Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a fusion between a Wordpress installation and a very custom shop solution which is placed in it's own folder ("/shop/") on the domain of the WP installation.

All pages within /shop/ loads Wordpresses header, and footer etc by including wp_load.php and WP functions.

However, when i set a cookie from PHP scripts inside the /shop/ folder, i can not retrieve it in the wordpress theme files...

```
var_dump($_COOKIE["orderID"]);
```

Returns the value inside /shop/ but NULL on regular WP pages.

My /shop/ pages have both my custom cookie parameters in it + WP stuff, but the regular WP pages have only it's own info.

I guess WP overrides my cookie in some way? can anyone hint me in the right direction, please? :)

Comment: why are you using cookie, and not just `$_SESSION`

Comment: Because i need the sustainability of a cookie in this case :) The clients might leave the computer for half an hour measuring stuff during the order process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a cookie set via PHP is only readable from the path the cookie is set on, so in this instance the cookie is only visible from the /shop/ url. Take a look at the `path` parameter of the php [set cookie](http://php.net/set_cookie) function, you'll need to set it to `/`

From the documentation:

> **path** - The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Chocking that i have not noticed this until now :)